# Find Points inside the Sentence and replace them with commas in Python

Tags: python, decimal

I want to split sentences in a document but firstly I want to find decimals,version numbers etc. in document and change the points to commas.
For example:

> I used the default "2.00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and
>   specified a key frame every ten frames.

I want change this sentence to the above form

> I used the default "2,00" quality setting in Premiere 2,0,1, and
>   specified a key frame every ten frames.

```
re.findall('\d*\.?\d+',s)
```

this code finds decimal but I couldn't change points to commas

Comment: I think "Premiere 2.0.1" should stay "Premiere 2.0.1". Version numbers are not separated with `,` even when decimals are.

Comment: Why does your output not also replace the `frames.` to `frames,`?

Comment: yes I know but when I try to split sentences it splits from points

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with group references. For this, first wrap the decimals in your regex into groups `(...)` and then use `\1` and `\2` in your replacement string to refer to those groups.

```
>>> s
'I used the default "2.00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d*)\.(\d+)', r'\1,\2', s)
'I used the default "2,00" quality setting in Premiere 2,0,1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.'
```

Also note that by making the `.` optional `\.?` the regex could also add a `,` into multi-digit numbers that do not have a `.` at all, so better remove the `?`.

However, IMHO the `.` in "Premiere 2.0.1" shoud *not* be replaced with a `,`. For this, you can use negative lookbehinds and lookaheads to ensure that the number is not followed by another digit or dot.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<![\d.])(\d*)\.(\d+)(?![\d.])', r"\1,\2", s)
'I used the default "2,00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use tha followin code sample

```
 s = 'I used the default "2.00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.I then ran the 320*240 movie'
s= re.sub(r'(\d*)\.(\d+)', r'\1,\2', s)
print(s)
```

output

```
I used the default "2,00" quality setting in Premiere 2,0,1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.I then ran the 320*240 movie
```

Comment: this code doesn't work for this string ''I used the default "2.00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.I then ran the 320*240 movie''

Comment: @gocen are you sure use the same code s = re.sub(r'(\d*)\.(\d+)', r'\1,\2', s) because I use it and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
import re

stringa = 'I used the default "2.00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.'

Ele = re.search(r'\s*([\d.]+)', stringa)

stringa.replace(Ele.group(),Ele.group().replace(".",",",1))
```

The result is:

```
'I used the default "2,00" quality setting in Premiere 2.0.1, and specified a key frame every ten frames.'
```

Comment: thank you but I want to change all points to commas except point of sentence. I want "Premiere 2,0,1," also